# Spring Security Configuration for JSON Body Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I've been working on a Spring Boot application and I'm trying to shift the authentication method from Basic Auth to sending credentials in the JSON body of a POST request.

When using Postman and the Basic Auth method (by entering the credentials in the Authorization tab), everything works fine and the authentication is successful. However, my goal is to send the credentials in the JSON body of the POST request.

I'm using Postman to send the POST request to the /api/user endpoint with the following JSON body:
{
"username": "stargazer@example.com",
"password": "123456"
}

Despite these settings, I keep getting a 401 error when using the JSON body method, but not with Basic Auth. I've checked the username and password, and they are correct.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Best,

When using Postman and the Basic Auth method (by entering the credentials in the Authorization tab), everything works fine and the authentication is successful. However, my goal is to send the credentials in the JSON body of the POST request.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your Sping Security setup? If Spring Security is on the classpath, Spring Boot automatically secures all HTTP endpoints with “basic” authentication. If you want anything else you need to configure.